# Check each value in the 3rd column of excel and if less than 4, change the row color? C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm creating an Excel sheet and filling it with values using c#.

Before I save it, I want to check the 3rd column of the excel sheet and check if each value is less than 4. If it is I want to change that row to red.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excel;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook worKbooK;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worKsheeT;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range celLrangE;
            int totalcount = 0;


            excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

            excel.Visible = false;
            excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

            worKbooK = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

            worKsheeT = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)worKbooK.ActiveSheet; worKsheeT.Name = "Model Results";


            worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1] = "Name";
            worKsheeT.Cells[1, 2] = "Id";
            worKsheeT.Cells[1, 3] = "Sales";



            for (int totalcount= 3; totalcount< dataGridView2.Columns.Count; )
            {
                GetSalesNumbers();

                worKsheeT.Cells[totalcount, 1] = Name;
                worKsheeT.Cells[totalcount, 2] =  Id;
                worKsheeT.Cells[totalcount, 3] = SalesNumber;

         totalcount ++;
            }



            celLrangE = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1], worKsheeT.Cells[totalcount + 5, 15]];
            celLrangE.EntireColumn.AutoFit();



            Excel.Range usedRange = worKsheeT.UsedRange;

            Excel.Range rows = usedRange.Rows;

            int count = 0;

            foreach (Excel.Range row in rows)
            {
                if (count > 0)
                {
                    Excel.Range firstCell = row.Cells[count,3];

                    string firstCellValue = firstCell.Value as String;

                    if (Convert.ToDouble(firstCellValue)<4)
                    {
                        row.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                    }
                }

                count++;
            }
```

But this doesn't work, it keeps getting the cell value as Null

Comment: You should be able to just use conditional formatting for that if you wanted to without having to resort to VBA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4146822/excel-shading-entire-row-based-on-change-of-value at a glance looks like the question you are asking

Comment: Run it in the debugger, checking other values to make sure you aren't off by one in the row or column.

Comment: Just noticed that you are creating the spreadsheet programatically so that question may not be quite as helpful as I first thought. However conditional formatting might still be worth looking into if it can be done programatically (I have absolutely no idea but I assume you can).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up using, I gave up on the other code

```
            celLrangE = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[1, 1],worKsheeT.Cells[totalcount + 5, 15]];
            celLrangE.EntireColumn.AutoFit();




            for (int row = 3; row <= totalcount; row++)
            {
                if (Convert.ToDouble(worKsheeT.Cells[row, 3].Value) < 4)
                {

                    Excel.Range rows = worKsheeT.Range[worKsheeT.Cells[row,1],worKsheeT.Cells[row,15]];

                    rows.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }


            }
```